# Virtual inheritance - gcc vs. vc++

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, virtual-inheritance

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2008 concerning virtual inheritance.

Consider the following example:

```
#include<iostream>

class Print {
    public:

    Print (const char * name) {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
};

class Base : public virtual Print {
    public:

    Base () : Print("Base") {}
};

class A : public Base {
    public:

    A () : Print("A") {}
};

class B : public A {
    public:

    B () : Print("B") {}
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    A a; // should print "A"
    B b; // should print "B"
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles just fine if I use gcc on my linux machine.
But if I try to build the same on windows with Visual Studio, the compilation fails with error message "error C2614: 'B': illegal member initialization: 'Print' is not a base or member."

Why does this not work?

Comment: The code compiles and works fine for me under VS2008.

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: Works as expected on Visual C++ 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the standard [class.base.init]: "Unless the mem-initializer-id names a nonstatic data member of the constructor’s class or a direct or virtual base of that class, the mem-initializer is ill-formed."

Evidently gcc interprets your case as legal as `Print` is a non-direct, but virtual base of `B`, however MSVC 2008 doesn't see `Print` as a virtual base of `B` - only a virtual base of a non-virtual base. (Incidentally, your example compiles on VS2005, so it's a surprising change in behaviour.)

I'd lean towards the `gcc` interpretation as being correct (otherwise the phrasing 'a direct base' would have been sufficient).

To work around this problem, you could derive `B` virtually from `Print`. As `Print` is already a virtual base of `A` this doesn't have any overall effect on the class layout or the number of base class `Print` sub-objects.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the standard. As you and others noted, the code compiles on various VS installations. Thus I recompiled the same code on another machine where the error message just disappeared. Maybe the VS installation on my machine is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio are you using?  The code you posted works fine for me with VC 9 (specifically 15.00.21022.08), and VC 6 as well as a few other compilers.

Are you sure that by mistake `class B` doesn't look like this in Visual Studio:

```
class B {  //  note: no base class
    public:

    B () : Print("B") {}
};
```

Comment: No, code is like in my example. See my comment on the other answer.

Comment: What exact version of the compiler does it fail for?  Change the "Suppress Startup Banner" property of the project or use the command line to get that information.